# Добавить array в SQL

Tags: sql, массивы, insert

У меня есть этот код:

```
$name = $_POST['game'];
$gameid = $_POST['gameid'];
$topshiriqid = $_POST['topshiriqid'];

$top1 = $_POST['top1']; if(empty($top1)){$top1 = 0;}
$top2 = $_POST['top2']; if(empty($top2)){$top2 = 0;}
$top3 = $_POST['top3']; if(empty($top3)){$top3 = 0;}
$top4 = $_POST['top4']; if(empty($top4)){$top4 = 0;}
$top5 = $_POST['top5']; if(empty($top5)){$top5 = 0;}
$top6 = $_POST['top6']; if(empty($top6)){$top6 = 0;}
$top7 = $_POST['top7']; if(empty($top7)){$top7 = 0;}
$top8 = $_POST['top8']; if(empty($top8)){$top8 = 0;}
$top9 = $_POST['top9']; if(empty($top9)){$top9 = 0;}
$top10 = $_POST['top10']; if(empty($top10)){$top10 = 0;}


$array = array($top1,$top2,$top3,$top4,$top5,$top6,$top7,$top8,$top9,$top10);

?>

<pre><? print_r($arr) ?></pre>

$result = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO table (gameid,topshiriqid,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`,`10`,date) VALUES ('$gameid','$topshiriqid','$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7','$value8','$value9','$value10','NOW()')");
```

и HTML код :

```
<form action="actions/addgame" method='post'>
<input type="hidden" name="game" value="mental">
<input type="hidden" name="gameid" value="<?=$_GET['id']?>">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table mental" id="myTable">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th><a href="javascript://" onclick="addRow('myTable');return false;"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a></th>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>4</th>
                <th>5</th>
                <th>6</th>
                <th>7</th>
                <th>8</th>
                <th>9</th>
                <th>10</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="12"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="<?=$words['topshiriqnomi']?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$n++?></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="idrow" value="<?=$nn++?>">
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top1[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top2[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top3[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top4[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top5[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top6[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top7[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top8[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top9[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top10[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$n++?></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="idrow" value="<?=$nn++?>">
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top1[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top2[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top3[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top4[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top5[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top6[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top7[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top8[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top9[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top10[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$n++?></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="idrow" value="<?=$nn++?>">
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top1[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top2[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top3[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top4[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top5[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top6[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top7[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top8[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top9[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top10[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$n++?></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="idrow" value="<?=$nn++?>">
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top1[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top2[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top3[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top4[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top5[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top6[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top7[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top8[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top9[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="any" name='top10[]' placeholder="<?=$words['sonkiriting']?>"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
            <div class="additional">
                <div></div>
                <button type="submit"><?=$words['save']?></button>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

и результат этот код :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 8
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 52
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 9
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 4
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 65
            [3] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 4
        )

)
```

теперь таким образом, он должен добавится в SQL базу:

```
id | gameid | taskid | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | date
 1 |   1    |   1    | 1 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 8 |52 | 6 | 8 | 5 | 4  | today 
 1 |   1    |   1    | 5 | 8 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 8 | 8 | 5 | 6 | 8  | today
 1 |   1    |   1    | 6 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 1 |65 | 8  | today
 1 |   1    |   1    | 6 | 4 | 8 | 6 | 4 | 9 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 4  | today
```

строки могут быть больше или меньше.
Спасибо за ранее

Comment: массивы в sql нельзя вроде добавлять. Ну короче, в книге, которую читаешь посмотри, наверняка будет что-то

Comment: дорогой, я знаю использовать foreach. но в этот код изменяющий 10 штук. Я делал это раньше с только один изменяющий...

Comment: в любом случае спасибо за ответ

Comment: Как видите, у вас на входе массив из массивов, причем с неправильной структурой. Можно например оставить входные массивы из POST в покое, не пытаясь собрать массив из колонок. Обойти их в цикле паралельно и вставлять в БД так, что бы было в записи `top1[0], top2[0], ....` следующая запись `top1[1], top2[1]`. А вообще я бы все переделал, начиная со структуры БД, 10 колонок явно сходного назначения обычно приводят к невозможности с ними нормально работать средствами sql.